# How to select * when using SQLAlchemy's query from_statement() method?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using from_statement() function do complex queries that requires multiple subtables which works fine apart from one thing, that you have to specify column names in query() calls.

e.g. If you want to get columns A and B from the following pseudo query

```
SELECT t1.colA AS A, t2.colB AS B FROM
(
    SELECT
        sth AS colA
    FROM
    (
        ...
) t1
...
```

then you'll have to specify A and B in your query()

```
session.query('A', 'B').from_statement(above_statement).all()
```

which can get annoying when you want to get say more than 5 columns from your query.

Is there some way to just make SQLAlchemy return whatever it gets from the query?
I've tried `query('*')` or just `query()` but neither works.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be to use `execute()`:

```
session.execute(above_statement).fetchall()
```

---

If you still want to use `query()`, then you can probably put all of your columns into a list and then unpack them:

```
cols = ['A', 'B']
session.query(*cols).from_statement(above_statement).all()
```

Comment: I think so as well but unfortunately I need query objects most of times to not break things.

Comment: Yes it works but I still have to list all the columns. Thanks anyway.

Comment: cols = ['A', 'B'] doesn't work when you have a complex nested query inside statement. I had to use cols = ['text(A'), text('B'])